# Does it make sense to use GIST features as input for ConvNet?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

I've been given a set of labeled images whose description arrays are 1x960 dimensional. Does it make sense to use these as input for my cnn? the 1x960 array is an output of the GIST feature extraction.

Comment: I believe the images are not 1x960 arrays, but their *descriptions* are.

Comment: @felipeduque yeah I thought it didn't make sense. Would these descriptors be useful in a conv net?

Comment: See my answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense. Convolution networks make use of convolution, which, in turn, exploits information contained in space (in images) or time (in sound data).

GIST features are not distributed over space nor time. It's just the result of a transformation *from* an image (which is distributed over space) to a one dimensional array.